# What is a "badboy" in reverse engineering

Tags: reverse-engineering

Ok so I've recently started doing some reverse engineering, and I keep coming across a term (I think) I have no idea what it means? A badboy?

```
00013F92   7E 24         JLE SHORT function.00013FB8                  ;  badboy
```

Could anyone explain?

Comment: Added example above. Hope its enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is the answer:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide

Search for "badboy".

> There are three types of breakpoints available to a reverse engineer:
> hardware, memory, and INT 3h breakpoints. Breakpoints are essential to
> a reverse engineer, and without them, live analysis of a module does
> him or her little good. Breakpoints allow for the stopping of
> execution of a program at any point where one is placed. By utilizing
> this, reverse engineers can put breakpoints in areas like Windows
> APIs, and can very easily find where a **badboy** message (a messagebox
> saying you entered a bad serial, for example) is coming from. In fact,
> this is probably the most utilized technique in cracking, the only
> competition would be a referenced text string search. This is why
> breakpoint checks are done over important APIs like `MessageBox`,
> `VirtualAlloc`, `CreateDialog`, and others that play an important role in
> the protecting user information process. The first example will cover
> the most common type of breakpoint which utilizes the INT 3h
> instruction.